# Multiple Inheritance Python with super()

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I have a situation where I have to initialize all the base classes

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("B.__init__")

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print("C.__init__")

class D(B,C):
    def __init__(self):
        print("D.__init__")
        super().__init__()

class E(D):
    def __init__(self):
        print("E.__init__")
        super().__init__()

x = E()
```

But the above code results in

```
E.__init__
D.__init__
B.__init__
```

My concern is Why wasn't C initialized?

Comment: Do you expect `super` to call both constructors?

Comment: Because `B` comes before `C` in the method resolution order, but doesn't contain a call to `super`

Comment: `super` is a little more complicated than it appears to be.  [Here's a good article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) by one of the Python developers about its uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two child classes provide the method (here it's `__init__`), Python calls the method only once and decides which one to call based on the method resolution order (MRO).

You can inspect the MRO by accessing the `__mro__` attribute.

```
>>> D.__mro__
(__main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.C, object)
```

When a method is invoked, the first place to look is `D`, then `B`, then `C`, then `object`.

Comment: [Associated documentation here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

Answer (score 1):

Because `super()` doesn't automatically call *all* of the inherited methods, only the next one up in the hierarchy. To ensure that all are called, you should have `super().__init__()` in the `__init__` method of `B` and `C` as well (in your specific scenario you only need to add it to `B`.